# Why my select with an expression in 'where' clause doesn't work?

Tags: sql++

I am trying to do something like

```
SELECT * 
FROM bucket bck
WHERE bck.type = 'Beer'
    and ARRAY_LENGTH(bck.path.to.array) > 1
```

Unfortunately, this select returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The predicate might be evaluated to false. Check by running this and see what values it returns
SELECT ARRAY_LENGTH(bck.path.to.array) FROM  \bucket bck WHERE bck.type = 'Beer';

Comment: this type of select returns length of each array even if it has the length of 1. I cannot still get only those documents which have array length greater than 1.
The question was - how can I get only those documents which have array greater than 1.

Comment: The query you provided should work. If not working check the data make sure all paths exist and it is array and has more than 1 element.